# What specific weather stripping is this?

Tags: weatherstripping

I'm replacing weather stripping on an exterior door. It's one of those metal doors where you can pull the handle up and turn the lock to lock it (I think it's some kind of child proofing). Anyway.

The top and sides are standard kerf. But the bottom is this. I've never seen it before. What is it and where can I get it? it's definitely 100% vinyl / rubber and 0% foam. Thanks!

[image: weather stripping]

[image: weather stripping]

[image: weather stripping]

Comment: We can presume that it's proprietary. Find something compatible or order it from the manufacturer.